# getRefreshInfo returning 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: yodlee

According to [Yodlee](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation/Aggregation_Services/Add_Site_Account), when you add a site to a user, you are meant to check the status of the site refresh using `getRefreshInfo` from the `RefreshInfo` locator

Whenever I attempt to use the getRefreshInfo on a user context, `Yodlee` throws a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error. This is even when using the sample java code that uses the `SOAP` API.

The actual call of `getRefreshInfo` is what is throwing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [getSiteRefreshInfo](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteRefreshInfo) API to check the status of the site refresh, this will help.
We'll get that document corrected.

Comment: @mdedetrich Great Cheers.